# Detect when device was activated

Tags: android

I am developing a system application. Which is located in the system partition. Is it possible to detect with system permissions the time when the device was activated? The application won't necessarily be installed before the first time the device is launched.

Comment: The user first opens the device after getting it from the store (similar to factory reset process)

Comment: As @awk said, use a BroadcastReceiver with ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED tag for this job.

Answer (score 0):

Following a successful (re)boot Android will issue the standard broadcast message called `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`. You can register to listen for this broadcast and then check the system time.

If you are interested in the time the user logs in to the system (this happens when the phone is unlocked) you can listen for the `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` broadcast.

For a complete list of Android broadcasts see `sdk/platforms/android-version/data/broadcast_actions.txt`

Comment: I need to be able to identify the first time the device completed the boot process. Identifying just the action itself does not help. nor can i save a flag because if the device has been launched 100 times before I first save the flag in shared prefs I will not be aware of this.